# How to update state of checking/unchecking condition in reducer function - redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a liSt of multiple items. Each item is having checkbox. Now i have to delete checked ones. But problem is my reducer condition. How to update that.

In my reducer, i am filtering out the unchecked ones. But problem is first time it is giving proper result but second time it is updating to wrong result. Because, in my list i am not checking true/false. It is always taking true.  **suppose, i have two checked items(eg. USA,Australia) then i uncheck Australia. In first iteration it is giving proper result. Now, if i uncheck USA and check again Australia. It is giving empty list.**

- It should give Australia

How to do that condition?

action code:

```
export const delToggleLocation = mruCode =>({
  type: DEL_SELECTED_CHECK,
  payload:mruCode
});
```

reducer code:

```
case 'DEL_SELECTED_CHECK':
        let newLists = state.isDeleted.filter( mruCode => mruCode !== action.payload) 
        console.log(newLists)
            return{
                ...state,
                isDeleted:newLists
            }
```

ComponentCode:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            chkitems: []
        };
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.checkedAllLocation = this.checkedAllLocation.bind(this);
        this.deleteChekedAll = this.deleteChekedAll.bind(this);
        this.deleteToggle = this.deleteToggle.bind(this);
        this.delAllChecked = this.delAllChecked.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null){
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }
    /**componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(nextProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData))) {
            console.log(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
            this.props.initLocationData(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }*/

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(prevProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData)))) {
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }

//other action codes

    deleteChekedAll(){
      this.props.delCheckedLocation()
    }

    deleteToggle(mruCode){
      this.props.delToggleLocation(mruCode)
    }
    delAllChecked(){
     this.props.delLocations()
    }


    render() {
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return (
                {this.state.open ? (
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row grid-divider">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <div className="col-padding">
                                    <div className="pos-div"><h4>Configured Location</h4><a data-toggle="toggle" data-target="#jdCheckbox2" className="jdClickable2"onClick={()=>this.deleteChekedAll()}>Delete All</a><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={() => this.delAllChecked()}>Remove Checked</button></div>
                                    <div><table className="table configTableColor"><thead>{this.props.conLocations.map((locc, index) => <tr key={index}><th><input type="checkbox" id="#jdCheckbox2" onChange={()=>this.deleteToggle(locc.mruCode)} checked={this.props.isDeleted.find(chkItems=>chkItems.mruCode===locc.mruCode)} /><label></label></th><th className="configLocationInfo">{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={() => this.handleRemove(locc.mruCode)} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead></table></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>) : null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        location: state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked: state.locationRed.isChecked,
        isDeleted: state.locationRed.isDeleted
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return  bindActionCreators({
        loadData,
        addLocation,
        addAllLocation,
        removeLocation,
        removeAllLocation,
        checkboxState,
        checkedLocation,
        initLocationData,
        selectAllBoxes,
        delCheckedLocation,
        delToggleLocation,
        delLocations
    },  dispatch);
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(NewLocationPanel);
```

**The list is like : [{mruCode:"1700",country:"USA"},{mruCode:"1000",country:"USA"}...]** .

How will i do select/deselect checkbox and update the list?

Comment: Are you comparing entire object here ? eg : mruCode !== action.payload ?

Comment: can't you just add back to the list the unselected one? two actions: `ADD_UNSELECTED`, `DEL_SELECTED`

Comment: @codekaizer...Thanks for your help.  Will you please little bit elaborate on this?

Comment: @rajm just filtering by id. Here is my case mruCode is the id

Comment: mruCode !== action.payload this cannot be done.  since payload is a object. try 'payload.something' for checking boolean value

Comment: Payload is not an object because payload:mruCode with mruCode a string makes payload a string as well.

Comment: Payload is not an object because payload:mruCode with mruCode a string makes payload a string as well.

Comment: how to do that checking/unchecking part. Because there is no boolean property in my list.